# How to add attachment column to a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-list

How to add a column in a sharepoint list which will contain all attachments of the corresponding item with hyperlink(clickable).

Comment: You can't add an attachment "column" in SharePoint. You can attach documents to list items though. That function is already built in.

Comment: I want to show attachment URLs in Javascript Dynamic table along with all other columns.

Comment: Then you need to create a custom application page that will do that.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to enable attachments for your list, to do this go to advanced settings and select enable attachments:

[image]

You will then find the option to add an attachment directly to your list item through the form, seen below:

[image]

To show in list view:

Add a new column title "Attachments" in Designer.

Within the TD tag of the new column replace with this code:

```
 <td id="ItemAttchment" class="ms-vb">
      <xsl:element name="SharePoint:AttachmentsField">
      <xsl:attribute name="runat">server</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="FieldName">Attachments</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="ControlMode">Display</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="Visible">true</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="ItemId">
          <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:element>
```

[Reference](http://amitphule.blogspot.in/2012/04/display-item-attachments-in-sharepoint.html)

Comment: i want column in the list which can show attachments link.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Hey found one really good article:                                                                           https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74dac191-5a9e-4970-a9f6-a501846f0bef/forum-faq-show-attachments-in-sharepoint-2013-custom-list-view?forum=sharepointgeneral&prof=required

Answer (score 0):

You can attach multiple files using that icon on the ribbon. But you have to enable attachments on the list's advanced settings

Answer (score 0):

Well, Yes you can add an attachment column to your list. You just need to append a custom button html to the NewForm.aspx.

Actually, the form columns are displayed in a tabular format in the newform(To confirm inspect the html of NewForm).

Just write a simple jQuery code to append the 'button td' into your form and on its click call the `UploadAttachment()` function [Sharepoint predefined function].

This is the code I used to append the attach button `td` in my form:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id*="_TextField"]').closest('table').append("<tr><td>Add Attachment</td><td><input type='button' onclick=' javascript:UploadAttachment()' value='Add File'/></td></tr>");
    
});
```

You can add this code to your form by adding a content editor web part.