# Add or update metadata without document file in sharepoint 2013 document library

Tags: document-library

I am not sure if it is possible or not OR there is some other way of doing this. I am just exploring it for a requirement to add client record in sharepoint document library with metadata(custom columns) like ClientCode, ClientName, Address, PhoneNo etc without associated document, at later stage when we get a document it can be uploaded for the same client.

I am adding document/updating metadata through sharepoint REST api.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution would be to go with a **list** instead of a (document) **library**. Lists function the same way as a library except that the items of a list are list items instead of files, as they would be with a library. So with lists the metadata wouldn't be tied to a file but instead to a list item.

Additionally you can attach a file to your list item afterwards, just as your requirement would be. To attach a file, you need to have the "Attachments to list items" Enabled from the list's Advanced Settings. See e.g. [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/204796/how-to-add-attachment-column-to-a-sharepoint-list) related question.

Get started by creating a custom list. The REST API functions for a list follow the same logic for a list as they'd for a library.